# Rclone Compression | zip | rar and data transfer

Tags: backup, rclone

I have been using rclone to back up google drive data to AWS S3 cloud storage. I have multiple google drive accounts whose backup happens on AWS S3. All those google drives have different numbers of documents.

I want to compress those documents into a single zip file and then it needs to be copied on S3.

Is there any way to achieve the same?

I referred to the link below, but it doesn't have complete steps to accomplish the task.

https://rclone.org/compress/

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rclone can't compress the files, but you can instead use a simple code to zip or rar the files and then use rclone to back them up to AWS.

If this is OK, I can explain the details here.